# Relational Algebra to SQL involving Natural Join

Tags: sql, relational-algebra

Since a Natural JOIN is implicitly done I don't think it should have a condition but I came across this problem and I was confused. Need help with translating this to SQL;

σSupplierId=’Datec’(r(Asset)*r(Supplier))

Comment: Natural joins assume there's a **single namespace** for all the columns of a database. That was the way to do things back in the 60s, when the whole database had a dozen tables at most. That was long time ago. Don't use natural joins.

Comment: What does "have a condition" mean? In SQL or in what relational algebra? Confused how? You don't need us to rewrite documentation, where are you stuck in what documentation? Is \* supposed to be natural join?

Comment: @TheImpaler, actually there was no time when people designed schemas to use the same column name for the 'same field' across different tables. `NATURAL JOIN` didn't appear in the SQL standard until 1990's, and even today many vendors don't support it. What's wrong here is expecting RA can be "translated" to SQL. Just don't even try that; and lecturers/textbooks should not introduce RA as some sort of 'alternative' SQL.

Answer (score 0):

The join `(r(Asset)*r(Supplier))` is inside parens. That sub-expression produces a relation.

The selection/restriction `σSupplierId=’Datec’( ... )` is outside the parens. It doesn't care what operation(s) apply inside the parens, providing they produce a relation.

So Join doesn't "ha[ve] a condition". It's the query overall that has the condition.

> Need help with translating this to SQL

I'll need to warn that there are many varieties of Relational Algebra, most with semantics that don't exactly correspond to SQL's. In particular Joins between tables with nullable columns tend to go badly. But

```
SELECT UNIQUE *
WHERE SupplierId = 'Datec'
FROM Asset NATURAL JOIN Supplier
```

BTW most vendors of SQL haven't implemented `NATURAL JOIN` and/or there are vendor-specific limitations on how you can use it. Refer to the vendor's documentation.

Answer (score -1):

There is nothing "natural" about the so-called `natural join` operator.  It has conditions -- they are simply not explicitly shown.

The conditions are equality matches between any columns with the same name in the two tables.  When there are such columns, then the "natural" join is equivalent to an `inner join` -- or outer join if you include a `left`, `right`, or `full` keyword.

If there are no columns with the same name, then the "natural" join is equivalent to a `cross join`.  Of course, a `cross join` is really an `inner join` with the condition `1=1`.

Note that a natural join does not take properly declared foreign key relationships into account, which is why I don't think it is "natural" at all.

Comment: What's your "properly" trying to say there? Are there "improperly" declared foreign keys? `NATURAL JOIN` in SQL might or might not faithfully implement Codd's operation denoted by the bowtie symbol in his work on Relational Algebra. The behaviour of Codd's operator is precisely specified without needing to "take ... FKs into account".

Comment: @AntC . . . I don't understand your comment.  SQL supports explicit declaration of relationships between tables, via foreign keys.  The so-called "natural join" does not use this.  I consider that an abomination, because it ignores the language constructs *explicitly* designed to provide that information.

Comment: Codd's original 1972 work on RA made no mention of FKs. The question here is chiefly about RA, not SQL. Expecting one formalism to have the same semantics and usage as another is mis-guided. _If_ your schema is designed in the expectation that Natural Join is the mechanism for relating relations, then same-naming attributes that correspond across different relations is a natural approach, and Natural Join naturally respects the design. I am of course well aware that SQL does it differently. Then it's SQL that is an abomination, in light of Codd's clear vision.

Comment: The acid test in SQL is if you `INNER JOIN` two tables that happen to have some column names in common, but you don't mention those names in the `ON` conditions. (Or you merely comma-list those tables in the `FROM`. This is irrespective of whether there's any FKs declared.) The result has two columns same-named, with potentially different values in the same row. Please explain how you distinguish same-named different values. Please explain what's "natural" or "proper" about that result. Please explain how the result could be a 'relation' by Codd's definition.

Comment: @AntC . . . This has nothing to do with Codd.  SQL as a standardized language and in almost all implementations supports foreign key constraints.  They are explicitly there to define the relationships among tables.  Common names (which I pretty much always use an recommendations) are NOT the way to *define* such relationships.

Comment: Well yeah. The real issue here is why do lecturers introduce RA at all on a course about SQL? They have different semantics and different implications for how you go about designing a schema. "translating" between them is in general impossible, and the whole idea is confusing for newbies. You seem to be falling into the same trap: SQL is not RA; don't criticise RA for not being SQL.